# How to deploy release artifacts to machine place in different subnet

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, cicd

We have Azure DevOps Server(On-Premises Version).
Here our release/deployment agent is on one subnet and servers where we have to deploy artifacts are in a different subnets.

Within one subnet I am able to deploy artifacts. But here I have to deploy artifact on machine places on different subnet.

I am not sure how can I do it.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

By using Deployment Agent Job , we can create link between build machine and server through which we can deploy.